# How to align span to stick to a div on the same line?

Tags: css, sass

### Introduction

My question is quite specific and I tried a lot of solutions from SO, but they don't work, because my problem is related to accessing dynamically generated DOM.

I have the following **generated HTML** (can't change anything in it, except the CSS):

```
<div style="flex: 1; z-index: 2;">
    <input type="text" />
</div>
<span style="display: none">X</span>
<span>A</span>
```

The 'A' in the span generates arrow icon for select/drop box. But the **span goes below the div** with the input.

---

[image: Screenshot of the UI problem]

---

### The question:

I want to align the second span (the first has display: none, so probably not a problem) to stick to the div. I don't have access to the dynamically generated HTML, but I kinda have access to the CSS *(using ::ng-deep to access the generated html with Angular 9)*.

How to align the span to stick with the div?

---

### What I've already tried, but didn't work:

I added float: right to the span and it works, but it's on a new line.

I changed the div to be display: inline-block, but it doesn't work. I tried to make the div and the span overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap, but still no success.

I would appreciate any tips to try to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the whole tags with `div`, and give `display: flex`.

It will be like this.

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div style="flex: 1; z-index: 2;">
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <span style="display: none">X</span>
    <span>A</span>
</div>
```

In this code, `wrapper` class has `display: flex`.

This attribute set all inside tags in one line because `flex-direction` is row.(default)

Comment: Absolute genius. Thank you very much. I'm not that well-informed of Flex, I should learn it. Again, thank you. It worked